# Permutation of two lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, list

I have two lists:

```
first = ["one", "two", "three"]
second = ["five", "six", "seven"]
```

I want every single combination of those two lists but with elements from the first list always to be in front. I tried something like this:

```
for i in range(0, len(combined) + 1):
    for subset in itertools.permutations(combined, i):
        print('/'.join(subset))
```

Where "combined" was these two list combined but that gave me all of the possibilities and i just want those where elements from the first list are in the first place. For example:

```
["onefive","twosix","twofive"]
```

etc. 
Does anyone have an Idea how could I make this?

Comment: In this example, do you want all 9 combinations?

Comment: Yes, I do want all 9 combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for:

```
>>> ["/".join(x) for x in itertools.product(first, second)]
['one/five', 'one/six', 'one/seven', 'two/five', 'two/six', 'two/seven', 'three/five', 'three/six', 'three/seven']
>>>
```

You can also do it without `itertools`:

```
>>> [x + "/" + y for x in first for y in second]
['one/five', 'one/six', 'one/seven', 'two/five', 'two/six', 'two/seven', 'three/five', 'three/six', 'three/seven']
>>>
```

Comment: The OP wants the cartesian product. Using `itertools.product` is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes using normal loops is the easiest:

```
["{}/{}".format(j,k) for j in first for k in second]

>>> ['one/five', 'one/six', 'one/seven', 'two/five', 'two/six', 
     'two/seven', 'three/five', 'three/six', 'three/seven']
```

Comment: I agree, they certainly are better. Upvoted.